# insert php code in html a tag

Tags: php, html, lang

I have a multi language website. I have three php files:

```
lang.de.php,lang.en.php, lang.hr.php
```

On index page I am changing text using this line of code:

```
<h2><?php echo $lang['TEXT'];?></h2>
```

Variable TEXT has different value in every lang.php file.

Now, I want to change the name of the .pdf file the same way, but I can't get it to work. I want to do something like this:

```
<a href="downloads/"<?php echo $lang['PDF_FILE'];?>".pdf"></a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Mind the quotes, you don't want to close the href attribute before passing the PDF name: `<a href="downloads/<?php echo $lang['PDF_FILE']; ?>.pdf">Download PDF</a>`.

Comment: Stupid me, thanks, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the double quotes before and after the

```
<a href="downloads/<?php echo $lang['PDF_FILE'];?>.pdf"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax to do this:

```
<a href="downloads/<?php echo $lang['PDF_FILE']; ?>.pdf"></a>
```

Comment: Apart from an extra space, this is an exact copy/paste of the answer already given 35 minutes ago.